# Screen Timeout Ubuntu 12.10 Cinnamon

Tags: display, cinnamon

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 with Cinnamon,

after roughly 10 minutes the screen turns black.  I have set "Turn screen off when inactive for:" to "Never" or tried high values (1h +), this does not affect this behaviour.
In the dconf-editor I located following entries:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.sleep-display-ac
```

setting to 0 did not have any effect

```
org.gnome.desktop.applications.screensaver.idle-activation-enabled
```

unsetting/unchecking did not have the desired effect

```
org.gnome.desktop.applications.session.idle-delay
```

setting it to 0 or very high values (100k) did not have any effect.

do you have any suggestions on how to approach this issue?
cheers
peter

Comment: Cinnamon uses Gnome 3, whereas I believe the system settings you are altering are for compiz/Unity.  I think Gnome still uses the power settings for things like screen blanking so you might want to investigate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a dirty workaround in some fedora forum. http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=269183

1. install the package xscreensaver
2. set the screensaver to run after minutes of inactivity=0 (i.e., never)
3. add the screensaver to the startup applications 
   /usr/bin/xscreensaver -no-splash

this worked in cinnamon.

the other approaches mentioned above only worked with unity

Answer (score 3):

Using the GUI look for "Preferences > Brightness and Lock". Or run

```
gnome-control-center
```

then choose "Brightness and Lock".

Comment: The GUI "Brightness and Lock" did have no effect on the problem in cinnamon. (As mentioned above - albeit not as clearly as I could have)
Nor did the settings in ... plugins/power or session.

Comment: That's a pity. It definitely works for me, using Cinnamon 1.6.6 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to disable screen blanking is to remove the Gnome screensaver by issuing this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I lack sufficient reputation to comment or vote up/down, but I can apparently give a separate answer--go figure. Summary: the only fix that WFM was xscreensaver. Details:

My own experience, today, with my GF's ubuntu 12.10 with cinnamon, was as follows:

1. In the past I had disabled screen blanking on inactivity by using `dconf-editor` to unset the proper key. I forget the name of that key :-) but it was something like the `org.gnome.desktop.applications.screensaver.idle-activation-enabled`
2. This week, I installed the updates requested by Software Updater, which I noticed included cinnamon packages. GF then complained that web videos went black after 10 minutes play.
3. I applied my previous fix with `dconf-editor`, restarted (just in case :-), and played video: no fix. I tried a few other `dconf-editor` hacks: all failed (with increasing irritation).
4. DuckDuckGo delivered me to this page.
5. I tried setting mainmenu>Preferences>Brightness and Lock appropriately, restarted (JIC), and played video: no fix.
6. I tried uninstalling `gnome-screensaver`): it was not installed. Instead I uninstalled `cinnamon-screensaver`, restarted (JIC), and played video: no fix.
7. I thought the `xscreensaver` answer sounded pretty dubious, but tried it anyway: installed, restarted, configured (via mainmenu>Preferences>Screensaver), and played video: it worked! Hour video stream played without blanking. Thank you, peter.